# How to keep this child bone in place?

Tags: armature, transforms, bones, parent

I have setup like this:

[image]

When I rotate the ROOT bone, Bone2 changes its position, even if I've unchecked "Inherit Rotation":
Gif: http://gfycat.com/PracticalDiligentHyracotherium

I would like to keep "Bone2" in place, no matter what rotation the ROOT bone has. How to achieve it?

.blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38113

Comment: Please show the panel where you have unchecked the option.

Comment: Here: http://i59.tinypic.com/27xibmp.jpg - "Inherit Rotation" unchecked. BTW. I've also uploaded my .blend file here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Remove the parent from the bone.

Comment: I want to have the ROOT bone as parent of both Bone1 and Bone2. But I've just managed to solve this: I've created a new "trueROOT" bone and parented old "ROOT" bone to it + changed parent of Bone2 from old "ROOT" to new "trueROOT". Now it works. Thanks for the help though! +1